# Xamarin Forms XAML - Unable to create multiple images from a list of URLs

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a List where the string is the url of an image.

I am trying to dynamically create a grid of images with the source being each url.

I have tried binding but it doesn't seem to work.  I also cannot access the x:Name of an image I created in Xaml. I am open to doing this in Xaml or in the code behind.

Any ideas of how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//imageList is a List<string> with your image urls in it
foreach(var i in imageList) {
  Image image = new Image();
  image.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(i));

  // you will need to add logic to calculate the Row/Column for each image
  myGrid.Children.Add(image,x,y);
}
```